# How do I activate these three rings?

Tags: psychonauts

I'm currently in Milla's mind trying to earn my learners permit for levitation. In her dance club are three rings that I'm supposed to activate. Jumping through them starts them turning, but I'm unable to get through all three at one time and end up falling back to the bottom, and they only spin for a short period of time. Am I missing something obvious, or is there a trick to getting them all turning at one time?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried gliding to get through them? You should have that by this point, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Fluttershy I have not. Playing with an Xbox controller on the PC. I recall the section that had something about floating, and not sure how I passed it because I couldn't figure out how to mimic the  move with the controller. Guess I can try looking that up.

Comment: @Fluttershy That was it. To float with an Xbox Controller is the LT. Feel free to answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To pass through all three rings in one go, you have to user your Thought Bubble to float.

To do this, simply jump, press and hold the left trigger, and you should start gliding down slowly. From there, steer yourself as needed to pass through all three rings.